# Issues with implementing an undo feature with stacks in Java

Tags: java, undo, memento

I am relatively new to Java programming. I am trying to make an application that acts a budget calculator and I wanted to implement an undo feature where I could perform multiple undos in a row to undo any numbers inputted in their respective fields. As of now the code can only perform one undo at a time. If I try to undo multiple times in a row, it will only undo once and prevent me from undoing further. Something I observed when trying to fix this was that the last text field in my UI does work as intended, where it will undo the whole textfield if I keep pressing the undo button. This makes me think I am implementing my stack incorrectly but I have yet to find a solution for this. The following are methods involved in the undo feature.

```
public void saveState() {
    Map<String, Double> incomeValues = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Double> spendingValues = new HashMap<>();

    // Get current values from income fields
    for (Map.Entry<String, JTextField> entry : incomeFields.entrySet()) {
        String fieldName = entry.getKey();
        JTextField field = entry.getValue();
        String text = field.getText();
        double value = text.isEmpty() ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(text);
        incomeValues.put(fieldName, value);
    }

    // Get current values from spending fields
    for (Map.Entry<String, JTextField> entry : spendingFields.entrySet()) {
        String fieldName = entry.getKey();
        JTextField field = entry.getValue();
        String text = field.getText();
        double value = text.isEmpty() ? 0 : Double.parseDouble(text);
        spendingValues.put(fieldName, value);
    }

    stateStack.push(new BudgetState(new HashMap<>(incomeValues), new HashMap<>(spendingValues)));
}

public void undo(int count) {
    while (count > 0 && !stateStack.isEmpty()) {
        stateStack.pop();
        count--;
    }

    BudgetState prevState = stateStack.isEmpty() ? null : stateStack.peek();
    restoreState(prevState);
    updateTotals();
}

public void restoreState(BudgetState state) {
    Map<String, Double> incomeValues = state.getIncomeValues();
    Map<String, Double> spendingValues = state.getSpendingValues();

    // Set values in text fields
    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : incomeValues.entrySet()) {
        String fieldName = entry.getKey();
        double value = entry.getValue();
        JTextField field = incomeFields.get(fieldName);
        field.setText(String.valueOf(value)); // Set text field value
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : spendingValues.entrySet()) {
        String fieldName = entry.getKey();
        double value = entry.getValue();
        JTextField field = spendingFields.get(fieldName);
        field.setText(String.valueOf(value)); // Set text field value
    }
}
```

This is the other class which handles serves as a container to store and represent the state of income and spending values within the budget calculator application.

```
package Budget;
import java.util.*;

public class BudgetState {
    private Map<String, Double> incomeValues;
    private Map<String, Double> spendingValues;

    public BudgetState(Map<String, Double> incomeValues, Map<String, Double> spendingValues) {
        this.incomeValues = new HashMap<>(incomeValues);
        this.spendingValues = new HashMap<>(spendingValues);
    }

    public Map<String, Double> getIncomeValues() {
        return incomeValues;
    }

    public Map<String, Double> getSpendingValues() {
        return spendingValues;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `undo` method you are using `peek` to get the previous state from the Stack.  The `peek` method is for inspecting the top element but it doesn't remove it.  Use `pop` instead.

Note that you are passing null to `restoreState` when the stack is empty but that method doesn't have special handling for the null case.